# Why getMonth returns different values on same date with different date formats

Tags: javascript, date

The Date.getMonth() returns different values for same date in different formats.

The first statement is in the UTC format.

The second one uses YYYY,M,DD format.

I didn't expect it to return a different value because it's the same date.
What is going on?

```
console.log(new Date('July 20, 69 00:20:18').getMonth()); // returns 6
console.log(new Date(1969, 7, 20).getMonth()); // returns 7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) (`new Date(string)` calls `Date.parse` internally)

Comment: Also, how are July 20 1969 and August 20 1980 at all the same date?

Comment: Yes it answers my question. fixed the year, but how come 7th month is august?

Comment: Months are indexed from zero.

Comment: Months are counted from zero (January = 0, February = 1, etc.)

Comment: In the second example it considers the month “7” to be August?

Answer (score 1):

For your first example - read MDN docs for [`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). It returns a zero-indexed numerical month representation where January is represented by `0`, and December by `11`. Thus, July is represented (correctly) by `6`.

The second one doesn't use a format per se, it's passing the values as parameters to the `Date` constructor. The [MDN docs for `Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) state that the parameter you're passing with a value `7` is also a `monthIndex`. Thus, to correctly notate July, pass `6` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method returns a zero based value. Meaning 0 indicates the first month. Creating a new `Date` object like in your second example follows the same principle.

See these [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

The months in a Date object are zero indexed. That means they range from 0 to 11.

`new Date('July 20, 69 00:20:18')` creates a Date with the month of July which has the index 6.

`new Date(1980, 7, 20)` creates a date with the month with the 7th index, which is August.

Here you can find more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

That diference happens because when using integer parameters to new Date(1980, 6, 20)
the month parameter starts in 0, not 1. example: 
0 - january 
1 - february  
... 
5 - july 
6 - august 
... 
11 - december 

So your result is

```js
var dateString = new Date('July 20, 69 00:20:18') // "1969-07-20T03:20:18.000Z"
var dateInt = new Date(1980, 7, 20) // "1980-08-20T03:00:00.000Z"

console.log(dateString.getMonth()); // 6
console.log(dateInt.getMonth()); // 7
```